# Why gcc show `unknown` in Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gcc

I would like to know why when I run `gcc -v` under Arch Linux, it shows the `unknown` word in these outputs:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

while in other distro, like ubuntu it shows the distro name, like, `ubuntu`:

```
 Using built-in specs.
 COLLECT_GCC=gcc
 COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu/5.1.0/lto-wrapper
 Target: x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Where did you install this gcc from?

Comment: `gcc` were Installed with the `core` packages when I was installing Arch.

Comment: Ok. Maybe check the compilation instructions for that package, then?

Answer (score 10):

As it was already mentioned in the comment, by default the target triplet is generated by [config.guess](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD) script. It's logic is fairly simple. First it uses `uname` to get some basic system information:

```
UNAME_MACHINE=`(uname -m) 2>/dev/null` || UNAME_MACHINE=unknown
UNAME_RELEASE=`(uname -r) 2>/dev/null` || UNAME_RELEASE=unknown
UNAME_SYSTEM=`(uname -s) 2>/dev/null`  || UNAME_SYSTEM=unknown
UNAME_VERSION=`(uname -v) 2>/dev/null` || UNAME_VERSION=unknown
```

These strings are combined and matched against hardcoded patterns. The result is also hardcoded:

```
case "${UNAME_MACHINE}:${UNAME_SYSTEM}:${UNAME_RELEASE}:${UNAME_VERSION}" in
...(snip)...
    x86_64:Linux:*:*)
        echo ${UNAME_MACHINE}-unknown-linux-${LIBC}
...(snip)...
```

For some systems it is possible to give more meaningful result, like IBM in "rs6000-ibm-aix".

Distribution maintainers simply override this string with their own (also hardcoded):

```
$ gcc -v
...(snip)...
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10'
...(snip)...
--target=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

GCC 6 will probably output x86_64-pc-linux-gnu by default: [updated config.guess](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/config.git/commit/?id=ca9bfb8cc75a2be1819d89c664a867785c96c9ba) in the upstream repository.

Comment: Amazing that GCC 6 is developing.

Comment: OMG, so `unknown` is hardcoded by default.

Answer (score 6):

That's the manufacterer part of the configuration/target triplet. The [Autobook](https://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_17.html) says about that:

```
manufacturer
   A somewhat freeform field which indicates the manufacturer of the system. This is often simply `unknown'. Other common strings are `pc' for an IBM PC compatible system, or the name of a workstation vendor, such as `sun'.
```

The [autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#System-Type) calls it `company`.

I'm not an expert in compilation with GCC, but it sounds like the information provided by that field is more of informational nature and `unknown` is just the default value GCC uses unless explicitly overwritten. GCC on Ubuntu 12.04 for example uses `x86_64-linux-gnu`, Debian 7s GCC `i486-linux-gnu`, so it's entirely possible to leave the field empty.

Comment: That's pretty much it. The `x86_64-linux-gnu` variety are shortcut targets, standing for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` or `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`. `gcc -v` shows the target it was compiled for, and `config.sub` gives the canonical triplet (look for it in `/usr/share/misc` on Debian-derived systems with `autotools-dev` installed).